# NodeJS Display HTML as text

Tags: html, node.js

I have some text that includes HTML tags (example: "This is a `<p>` tag").
How do I display that text "as is" without my nodeJS page interpreting the tag as a real "`<p></p>`" tag?

If I use the `&lt;` and `&gt;` HTML entities, the entities aren't interpreted and are displayed like this ("This is a `&lt;p&gt;` tag") which is what I **don't** want.

Comment: How would you do it in HTML?

Comment: If you are referring to using node.js as a http server (without any framework), then the default is to print in text, but if you want to explicitly set it to text you can set the content type. But I suspect you are referring to some other use case, could you be more specific?

Comment: This is the line I am displaying where 'group.title' is the var that "This is a `<p>` tag" is assigned to.

   '<p class="title"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="'+group._id+'">'+group.title+'</a></p>`

I'm using express.

Comment: Try this workaround, it should work: `<code>This is a <p> tag</code>`. This problem is due to how express escapes it's variables, I think there might be a better solution, though.

Comment: Nope. Sorry - it still interprets the `<p>` tag. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: I'm thinking of replacing the brackets with some extended ASCII character that looks similar. If that doesn't work, then I'll just live with the problem and try to remember to not use HTML tags in that field.

Comment: @Steve That's quite odd, considering you tried with HTML escaping them. Maybe it has to do with the templating engine you are using as suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the specific way you're creating HTML pages in Node, but if you use a templating language such as Jade or EJS, you can turn off escaping like so:

In [Jade](http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#escaping):

```
p.title
  a(href='javascript:void(0)' id='#{group._id}') !{group.title}
```

In [EJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs):

```
<p class='title'>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="<%= group._id %>"><%- group.title %></a>
</p>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm - thanks!
I am using Handlebars which has an equivalent method of controlling escaping.